# Storing datetime in date format, Flask With Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In Flask using pymongo I want to store datetime in date format in mongodb but it stores in array or string format with the code I have written

myscript

```
date_post=time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %p")  # if i store this in mongo 
                                             db it stores in string datatype
date_post=time.strptime(date_post,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
# if i store this in mongo db it stores in Array datatype
print(type(date_post))


jd = mongo.db.rest_create_job_add

job_id =jd.insert({'Country':country,'State':state,'City':city,'Spoc_Name':spoc_name,'Spoc_EMP_ID':spoc_empid,'SPOC_Email':spoc_email,'Spoc_Mobile_No':spoc_mobile,'Spoc_Work_or_Direct_No':spoc_workno,
    'date_posted':date_post,'band_range':band_range})
```

in mongodb it stores `date_posted` in `Array datatype` whereas i need it to be stored in date format.

any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming `date_post` is a `datetime` object. If it is you want to pass it directly to `jd.insert` without any conversion. Mongo Db driver takes care to convert it to the corresponding [BSON UTC Datetime type](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any updates on this?